# Adding together values from QLineEdit widgets generated with a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

I'm trying to add together the values of QLineEdit boxes generated using a for loop. However it's only adding the input of the last input and the rest are being skipped.

```
for i in range(self.numInputsToAdd):
    self.additionalInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)] = QLineEdit(self)
    self.additionalInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
    self.additionalInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setText("1")
    self.additionalInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)].setPlaceholderText("Additional Mod Input #" + str(i + 1))
    self.vertCol.addWidget(self.additionalInputs["addnlInput" + str(i + 1)])
```

This is how I'm currently generating the inputs to be added, `self.numInputsToAdd` is the value of another qlineedit from a pop up window after a button is clicked. The above code puts the inputs in a dict named `self.additionalInputs` with the name of `addnlInput1, addnlInput2..etc`

After a 'Roll Dice' button is clicked it triggers a function which grabs the items of the additionalInputs dict and attempts to add them together, assign them to another variable and add that variable to another which is the output of `randint(1, n)`

```
self.dieResult = str(randint(1, n))
self.newinputlist = {}
for keys, vals in self.additionalInputs.items():
    self.newinputlist[keys] = self.additionalInputs[keys].text()
    print(self.newinputlist[keys])
    self.modDieResult = str(int(self.dieResult) + int(self.inputs['modInput'].text()) + int(self.newinputlist[keys]))
```

Above is the relevant code to the 'die roll'

[Here is a functional working example.](https://pastebin.com/Y2TFd5fJ) Currently you need an input in the top Modifier input box. The problem lies with the input boxes that are generated with the 'More Modifiers?' button. That is where it only adds the bottom modifier input to the very top modifier input box that is there at app launch.

I am using python 3.7.2 and windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is not Qt specific, but in the final line of your loop:

```
self.modDieResult = str(int(self.dieResult) + int(self.inputs['modInput'].text()) + int(self.newinputlist[keys]))
```

Here you calculate the result `self.modDieResult` on *each* iteration of the loop. The result of this calculation is assigned to `self.modDieResult` meaning it will end up with only the final calulcated value at the end.

To do a running sum, you need an additional variable e.g.

```
self.dieResult = str(randint(1, n))
self.newinputlist = {}

# Store the initial modInput value.
modInputResults = int(self.inputs['modInput'].text())

for k, v in self.additionalInputs.items():
    self.newinputlist[k] = self.additionalInputs[k].text()
    print(self.newinputlist[k])

    # On each loop, add the value for the additional elements.
    # Note you could do: int(v.text()) without the additional newinputlist.
    modInputResults = modInputResults + int(self.newinputlist[k])

self.modDieResult = self.dieResult + modInputResults
```

Note: I also changed the `keys`, `values` to `k`, `v` since the variable only contains a *single* key or value, not multiple.